# How to get nested keys of a json stream using jq

Tags: json, schema, jq

I am trying to design a number of relational tables to hold parsed output of various json streams. The data streams have quite complex structure and to facilitate the table design, I need to know every level of nested keys for every stream. And I am lost about how to get every nested keys out of the stream using jq. The following is a simplified representative json stream.

```
{
  "startAt": 0,
  "total": 5315,
  "issues": [
    {
      "id": "44269",
      "name": "someName",
      "fields": {
        "fixVersions": [
          {
            "id": "11401",
            "releaseDate": "2016-09-30"
          }
        ],
        "status": {
          "id": "10110",
          "statusCategory": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Done"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "44270",
      "key": "LEAD-XXXX",
      "fields": {
        "assignee": {
          "id": "10111",
          "name": "Don"
        },
        "status": {
          "id": "10110",
          "statusCategory": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "inProgress"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I am expecting the following output. I would be more than happy to have a better approach helping me with the table design.

```
startAt
total
issues: []
issues:id
issues:name
issues:key
issues:fields
issues:fields:fixVersions: []
issues:fields:fixVersions:id
issues:fields:fixVersions:releaseDate
issues:fields:status
issues:fields:status:id
issues:fields:status:statusCategory
issues:fields:status:statusCategory:id
issues:fields:status:statusCategory:name
issues:fields:assignee
issues:fields:assignee:id
issues:fields:assignee:name
```

How can I get the nested keys for the above stream using jq. Appreciate the help very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would be more than happy to have a better approach ...

If I were you, I'd start with (and maybe end with) the following:

```
[paths(scalars) | map(if type == "number" then 0 else . end)]
| unique
| .[]
```

With your example, using the -cr command-line options, this produces:

```
["issues",0,"fields","assignee","id"]
["issues",0,"fields","assignee","name"]
["issues",0,"fields","fixVersions",0,"id"]
["issues",0,"fields","fixVersions",0,"releaseDate"]
["issues",0,"fields","status","id"]
["issues",0,"fields","status","statusCategory","id"]
["issues",0,"fields","status","statusCategory","name"]
["issues",0,"id"]
["issues",0,"key"]
["issues",0,"name"]
["startAt"]
["total"]
```

You could get even closer to what you've indicated you want my mapping the numeric 0s to a string, but then you have to be careful about potential conflicts between that string and key names.  To illustrate:

```
[paths(scalars) | map(if type == "number" then "[]" else . end)]
| unique
| .[]
| join(":")
```

produces:

```
issues:[]:fields:assignee:id
issues:[]:fields:assignee:name
issues:[]:fields:fixVersions:[]:id
issues:[]:fields:fixVersions:[]:releaseDate
issues:[]:fields:status:id
issues:[]:fields:status:statusCategory:id
issues:[]:fields:status:statusCategory:name
issues:[]:id
issues:[]:key
issues:[]:name
startAt
total
```

Notice that this approach yields essentially the same results as the schema-inference-based approach. That is a Good Thing.

#### Using INDEX/2

Using `unique/0` as above has two potential disadvantages: (1) the ordering of the output does not reflect the ordering in the data; (2) efficiency (though in practice that is unlikely to be a real issue except maybe for JSON texts with a huge number of leaf paths).

In any case, `INDEX/2` could be used instead of `unique`. In case your jq does not have `INDEX/2`, its def is given here.

In short:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({};
    .[$row|idx_expr|
      if type != "string" then tojson
      else .
      end] |= $row);

INDEX(paths(scalars)
      | map(if type == "number" then "[]" else . end); .)
| .[]
| join(":")
```

yields:

```
startAt
total
issues:[]:id
issues:[]:name
issues:[]:fields:fixVersions:[]:id
issues:[]:fields:fixVersions:[]:releaseDate
issues:[]:fields:status:id
issues:[]:fields:status:statusCategory:id
issues:[]:fields:status:statusCategory:name
issues:[]:key
issues:[]:fields:assignee:id
issues:[]:fields:assignee:name
```

#### Paths to empty arrays

If you want paths to empty arrays to be reported as well, you could (for example) simply change "paths(scalars)" to "(paths(scalars), paths(arrays))".

Comment: you sure do have solid understanding and expertise with jq to say the least. I am going to learn a bit about jq programming just looking at your code itself. Empty arrays is a good catch.  For my purpose, your first solution is good enough. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a schematic representation of your data, you might like to consider an approach based on *schema inference*.

For example, using the `schema` function as defined at https://gist.github.com/pkoppstein/a5abb4ebef3b0f72a6ed, your input results in the following inferred schema:

```
{
  "startAt": "number",
  "total": "number",
  "issues": [
    {
      "fields": {
        "assignee": {
          "id": "string",
          "name": "string"
        },
        "fixVersions": [
          {
            "id": "string",
            "releaseDate": "string"
          }
        ],
        "status": {
          "id": "string",
          "statusCategory": {
            "id": "number",
            "name": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "id": "string",
      "key": "string",
      "name": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you filter that through `paths(scalars)`, you get:

```
["startAt"]
["total"]
["issues",0,"fields","assignee","id"]
["issues",0,"fields","assignee","name"]
["issues",0,"fields","fixVersions",0,"id"]
["issues",0,"fields","fixVersions",0,"releaseDate"]
["issues",0,"fields","status","id"]
["issues",0,"fields","status","statusCategory","id"]
["issues",0,"fields","status","statusCategory","name"]
["issues",0,"id"]
["issues",0,"key"]
["issues",0,"name"]
```

Except for the ordering, these results are the same as obtained using the more direct approach; this I would suggest validates both approaches.

Answer (score 1):

`paths` is definitely the right approach but getting the exact output requested is a little cumbersome.  Here is a filter which does this except for the precise ordering:

```
def normalize:    # convert paths to requested structure
    if .[-1]|type=="number" then .[-1]="[]" else . end
  | map(select(type!="number"));

def collect:      # collect unique normalized paths into an object
  reduce (paths|normalize) as $p (
     {}
   ; if getpath($p)==null then setpath($p;null) else . end
  );

def colonize($p): # convert object back into : separated paths
    keys_unsorted[] as $k
  | (if $p=="" then $k else "\($p):\($k)" end) as $n
  | $n, (.[$k] | if type=="object" then colonize($n) else empty end);

def summary:      # final output without redundant foo: if foo:[] is present 
    [ collect | colonize("") ]
  | map(select(endswith(":[]"))|.[:-3]) as $remove
  | map(select($remove[[.]]==[]));

summary[]
```

Sample Run (assuming filter in `filter.jq` and data in `data.json`)

```
$ jq -Mcr -f filter.jq data.json
startAt
total
issues:[]
issues:id
issues:name
issues:fields
issues:fields:fixVersions:[]
issues:fields:fixVersions:id
issues:fields:fixVersions:releaseDate
issues:fields:status
issues:fields:status:id
issues:fields:status:statusCategory
issues:fields:status:statusCategory:id
issues:fields:status:statusCategory:name
issues:fields:assignee
issues:fields:assignee:id
issues:fields:assignee:name
issues:key
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZPBjpswEIbveQp3xAEkiCDZ3WqJOKya3qqqp6oStSpvmGTZgE1t022a5NWbjoGwyd7qA3js@f/5PIbnn6c9GCu0fbCQxiFYZUUF6e08uQ2hNKZFA2m@h7KAFG5uZnf3EIIUNVJoVI2f3TSEdYlVQZl7mv3@itqUSl4Ik@QmTihNY4XC4FJYp5/FyV0U30fzGI48dBi27Tx6TZwkMZyXP5Bko/TuvD0fKZZKIhxphK@U751wi5QNnz4@LKNvNK4ohTHlRiJeVUvg0hSO/4k0G9Wl/KLVRqMxHRg/Hk4FrplUuhZV@QdTNmE0yjWb5lHCD3bXYJaBbOtH1MDsE8p@J4OcA8PKIJsylAXJDqwWjW@okSvrO@G7URgEi8nEFVqpym2nlK6xaFfI/EbYJ3MYCQImDPMa5ncgbH9074Uj2qB1ub7XBFkm26rqccy4vHCLwTXURWElyd6p086aLsH8aKVR2mKR867stjuGT8W8ho49HNjb9p7wvVPTcxuA8@9ZZSfyZMj8ae5tOQVkMHROPT7TeQejVwg5YGLd2F1nNXCatq6F3vWI@blfZDlqAQLG37abHMxLSV2gL5tTuw/TPI3mvAfUWKtf@FYyLOf5lPMsy3l3R0P5nJ9Of1Vj3b9yiiLX16iUTWsp0OIlUq2l4B8)

Note that there is a problem here with empty arrays.  If there are empty arrays in your data this filter will report them as ordinary fields because the corresponding path returned by `paths` won't end in a number.  The easiest way to compensate for this is to map the empty arrays to something non-empty like `[{}]` first.  e.g.

```
def walk(f):  # defined here in case your jq doesn't have it
    . as $in
  | if type == "object" then reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key (
        {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
    elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
    else f
    end;

  walk(if .==[] then [{}] else . end)
| summary[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear -- it is quite easy to write a jq filter that produces the output in the format originally envisioned, though that format is unlikely to be of general use.

The following approach obviates the need to use `walk/1` to handle the special case of empty arrays.  It uses `unique` only because `INDEX/2` is not included in jq release 1.5 (*).

With the example input and the `-r` command-line option, the following:

```
 [paths as $p
  | if (getpath($p)|type) == "array" then $p + [" []"]
    elif ($p[-1]|type) == "number" then empty
    else $p
    end
    | map(select(type != "number"))]
 | unique
 | .[]
 | join(":")
```

produces:

```
issues: []
issues:fields
issues:fields:assignee
issues:fields:assignee:id
issues:fields:assignee:name
issues:fields:fixVersions: []
issues:fields:fixVersions:id
issues:fields:fixVersions:releaseDate
issues:fields:status
issues:fields:status:id
issues:fields:status:statusCategory
issues:fields:status:statusCategory:id
issues:fields:status:statusCategory:name
issues:id
issues:key
issues:name
startAt
total
```

(*) `unique` can easily be avoided here by using `INDEX/2`, as described elsewhere on this page.

Comment: Designing a RDBMS schema/table structure to hold json output from known sources has its own share of problems because of embedded array and/or objects in the stream. Knowing the exhaustive object and array structure   helps defining the table structure, normalization and related design issues. And this requirement prompted the question. The output format is one of the ways to represent the input thought process and it need not be a generalized one. The solutions provided here are good starting points for me to dig deeper in the jq world

Comment: @kishore - It sounds to me as though you need a schema inference engine, such as defined in schema.jq, mentioned elsewhere on this page. It can be used to infer a "universal schema" subsuming multiple sources, or to infer multiple schemas corresponding to each source.